# django-pyodbc-azure. Invalid object name 'django_session'

Tags: sql-server, django, azure, pyodbc, django-mssql

I need help with setting up my project. I used `django-pyodbc-azure` and I have this in my `settings.DATABASES`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { 'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc','NAME': 'DBNAME','USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': '10.xx.xx.xx,1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0',
        },
    },
}
```

Sorry I don't know how to format the code above.

I don' know the problem is, but it returns an error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][
>   SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_session'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000]
>    [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be
>    prepared. (8180)")

How do I fix this?

Comment: It appears you are running on Windows with the SQL Server Native Client, is that right? What version of SQL Server and Windows? Did you do an initial `python manage.py migrate`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user@myserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc-azure